# From twistors and supertwistors to hypertwistors and hypersupertwistors

Tags: twistor

Twistor and supertwistor methods are, currently, a framework for General Relativity, beyond General Relativity and string/brane theories. What are hypertwistors and hypersupertwistors and their motivation, even when twistors and supertwistors we can have indeed more than standard theories? A gentle introduction to hypertwistors and hypersupertwistor (hypersuperpace) should be welcome.

Comment: All I could find are those three papers by the same authors and they don't look very inspiring
https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0601020v1
https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0502218v1
https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0406121v1
In what context have you found hypertwistors?

Comment: General tip: Consider adding context & references in order to receive useful concise answers.